# Running Python3 script via PowerShell action in Power Automate Desktop, with dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, python-venv, power-automate-desktop

I'm really hoping someone understands how to solve this, because it's so hard to see what's actually happening inside Power Automate Desktop.

I am able to run Python3 scripts in PowerShell using a virtual environment for dependency resolution, like this:

```
C:\path\to\script\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
python C:\path\to\script\script.py
```

I am also able to run Python3 scripts through PAD PowerShell actions, including the one in question, using the same code; however, it seems to be unable still to resolve dependencies, as it only outputs a few test lines, and doesn't make it past the first library function call.

What might be happening?
How can I actually activate the virtual environment, if that's the problem?
Is there a different way I should be managing the dependencies? I've tried adding the site-packages folder to the user environment var PATH with no luck.

Thanks